# Print to a receipt printer PRP-085IIIT

Tags: command, printers

I've been searching the net over a week, and I still can figure out how receipt printer works especially how to send commands.

I need to print a receipt to this "PRP-085IIIT" printer. The printer is connected  via USB and using a Generic\Text Only driver.

I found this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091 to send raw data to the printer. I manage to print but I can't cut the page at the end. From what I found, I need to sent command to the printer in order to cut the page. That my main problem, I can't figure out how to send command to the printer.

Also I'm using C# to develop my application.

Any kind of help would be appreciated because I'm out of resources.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send command for the cutting of the receipt, you just have to set the DIMM setting at the back of the printer. See the manuals for more info abt the setting.